# Do we need to take cache thrashing into account with CUDA?

Tags: c, caching, memory, optimization, cuda

I'm not familiar with the workings of GPU memory caching, so would like to know if the assumptions of temporal and spatial proximity of memory access associated with CPUs also applies with GPUs. That is, programming in CUDA C, do I need to take into account C's row-major array storage format to prevent cache thrashing?

Many thanks.

Comment: Why don't you benchmark it?

Comment: Thanks. I've not completed writing the code yet, but will try once it's functioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, very much.

Say you are fetching 4 byte integers for each thread.

### Scenario one

Each thread is fetching one integer with the index of its thread id. That means thread zero is fetching a[0], thread 1 is fetching a[1] etc... As with the GPU it will fetch in cache lines of 128 bytes. As a coincidence a warp is 32 threads, ergo 32*4 = 128 bytes. This means for one warp, it will one do one fetch request from memory.

### Scenario two

If the threads are fetching in total random order with a distance between the indexes is greater than 128 bytes. It will have to make 32 memory requests of 128 bytes. This means that you will for each warp fill the caches with 32 times more memory, and if your problem is big your cache will be invalidated up to 32 more times than scenario one.

This means that if you would request memory that would normally reside in the cache in scenario one, in scenario two it is highly likely that it have to be resolve with another memory request from global memory.

Answer (score 0):

No and yes. No because the GPU does not provides the same kind of "cache" that CPU.

But you have many other constraints that makes the underlying C array layout and how it is accessed by concurrent threads very important for performances.

You may have a look at this page for basics about [CUDA memory types](http://www.cvg.ethz.ch/teaching/2011spring/gpgpu/cuda_memory.pdf) or [here](http://supercomputingblog.com/cuda/cuda-memory-and-cache-architecture/) for more in depth details about cache on Fermi GPU.